# Akka Persistence: ReadJournal.runFold never returns

Tags: scala, akka, event-sourcing, akka-persistence

I am experimenting with Akka, and more specifically Akka Persistence, for the first time.  I am ultimately trying to implement a small toy program to replicate Akka's use in an event-sourced application.  I have had success up until the point where I attempt to use `ReadJournal` to project my event stream into my domain.

```
def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val commands: EmployeeCommandStream = TestEmployeeCommandStream(EmployeeId.generate())

    implicit val executionContext = ExecutionContext.global
    implicit val system = ActorSystem.create("employee-service-actor-system")
    implicit val mat: Materializer = ActorMaterializer()(system)

    val service = system.actorOf(Props(classOf[EmployeeActor], commands.employeeId))

    commands.stream.foreach(command => service.tell(command, noSender))

    lazy val readJournal = PersistenceQuery(system).readJournalFor("inmemory-read-journal")
      .asInstanceOf[ReadJournal
      with CurrentPersistenceIdsQuery
      with CurrentEventsByPersistenceIdQuery
      with CurrentEventsByTagQuery
      with EventsByPersistenceIdQuery
      with EventsByTagQuery]

    println(Await.result(
      readJournal
        .eventsByPersistenceId(commands.employeeId.toString, 0L, Long.MaxValue)
        .map(_.event)
        .runFold(Employee.apply())({
          case (employee: Employee, event: EmployeeEvent) => employee.apply(event)
        }),
      Duration("10s")
    ))     
}
```

My domain's only aggregate is the `Employee`, so I'm just starting up an actor with the UUID representing some employee, and then I'm issuing some commands for that employee.

In the example above, if I remove the `println(Await.result(...))` and replace `.runFold(...)` with `.runForeach(println)`, the events persisted in my actor are printed as expected for each given command.  So I know that the write side of my program and `ReadJournal` are both working as expected.

As-is, my program terminates with

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Futures timed out after [10 seconds]
```

So now my question is, why can't I perform `runFold` to ultimately replay my event stream?  Is there a better way to do this?  Am I simply misusing the API?

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `runFold`, you are folding over a stream. The fold will effectively terminate when the stream itself terminates.

By using `eventsByPersistenceId`, you are asking for a never ending stream of live events, thus your fold won't terminate.

You should use `currentEventsByPersistenceId` instead for your use case. This variant will stream the events currently available on the journal and terminate.

See https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5.6/scala/persistence-query.html#eventsbypersistenceidquery-and-currenteventsbypersistenceidquery

Comment: Ah, thanks for your help -- one things I wasn't able to find in the docs: what are the ways a stream can terminate?  I tried `system.stop(service)`, attaching a callback with `registerOnTerminate(...)` and exiting the program, etc.  Is there a straightforward way that Akka provides for terminating the stream?  Is the key to provide a terminal `Sink`, so that there is some notion of how the stream should eventually terminate?

Comment: `KillSwitch`es, see https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/scala/stream/stream-dynamic.html#uniquekillswitch and https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/scala/stream/stream-dynamic.html#sharedkillswitch

Comment: You're a legend, thanks bud.  I promise to dive deeper into the docs next time :p